# How to strip all the php tag in a php file

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to strip all the PHP tag from the PHP file. I am trying to  remove PHP tags because I want to get all the html href value's of all a tags. I don't know whether is it possible or not? Can anyone help me to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

```
$removedPhptags = preg_replace('/^<\?php(.*)(\?>)?$/s', '$1', "http://localhost/project/test.php");
```

test.php

```
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div> <a href="test1.html" title="test"></a>
          <?php

         include './menulink.php'; 

        $result_array="123";

        if ($result_array=="123")
        {
        ?>
          <a href="test4.html" title="tesdfhdfhdfht2"></a>
          <?php 


        else{

        ?>
          <a href="test5.html" title="tedfhdfhst"></a>
          <?php


        }

        ?>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

menulink.php

```
                <html>
            <head>
            <title>Test</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div> <a href="menulink1.html" title="test">m1</a> <a href="menulink2.html" title="test2">m2</a>
              <?php

            $result_array="123";

               if ($result_array=="123")
            {
            ?>
              <a href="menulink3.html" title="tedfhdfhst">m3</a> <a href="menulink4.html" title="tesdfhdfhdfht2">m4</a>
              <?php 
            }

            else{

            ?>
              <a href="menulink5.html" title="tedfhdfhst">m5</a> <a href="menulink6.html" title="tesdfhdfhdfht2">m6</a>
              <?php


            }

            ?>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: where do you want to remove the tag in php or in js?

Comment: PHP content will not display in browser when you will run code. You will only get html content.

Comment: Why not just remove your PHP code manually if you don't want it?

Comment: js is better..i am trying also in bith code

Comment: Magnus Eriksson: Because i want to get all the html element details before run inside if and else condition also break i need all the html code

Answer (score 4):

there are two issues with what you are doing here,

the first problem is that [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) accept the third parameter as a `String` , you may need to pass the file content to this as a string

the second problem is that you are trying to require your file as a HTTP call, you need rather to get the file content, actually by calling the link itself you are trying to get the ***rendered*** output.

```
$content = file_get_contents("path/to/file"); // not a file link
$removedPhptags = preg_replace('/^<\?php(.*)(\?>)?$/s', '$1', $content);
```

Comment: i have tested but i am not get anything..not working

Comment: try to var_dump your $content variable and check what's happening there

Comment: `$content = file_get_contents("test.php");`

Comment: Thank you so much Hassan. but one more help i have included one more php file inside menulink.php this file also contaning same like that data how c we can get including file also? please see my edit code.

Comment: short answer: in a direct way NO. but as a work around you may make a use of the [get_included_files](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) function in PHP.

Comment: Hi Hassan..i am new in php so please help me how we can use that get_included_files funtion to get all the href details. can you send your perfect code by jsfiddle?

Comment: you need to get the [`included`](http://php.net/include) or the files that `href`ed in your HTML page?

Comment: that files href in my html page.... means i want to get included php file's html href link also i need

Comment: you can not, read more about the [href](https://html.com/attributes/a-href/) attribute meaning, also have a look at the [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: i want to get html content of included php file also because menulink.php file also have if else condition rite?

Comment: See my code..not working.   $content = file_get_contents("./test.php"); 
 
 $included_files = get_included_files($content);

 foreach ($included_files as $filename) {
  
  $content = file_get_contents($filename); 
   
 }

 $removedPhptags = preg_replace('/^<\?php(.*)(\?>)?$/s', '$1', $content);
 echo $content;

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the answer already given by @hassan, your regular expression will not work:

- You should not link the opening php tag to the start of the string.
- You don't want a greedy match as that will take everything from the first opening tag to the last closing tag. Assuming that is what you need.

So all you need as far as the regular expression goes is:

```
<\?php(.*?)\?>
^            ^ not bound to start nor end (no ^ and $)
         ^ lazy matching, taking as few characters as possible
```

[An example](https://regex101.com/r/HnXje6/1).

Comment: wow..samething i am expection using coding..how we can do it using php or javascript

Comment: @sarancheln Just put this regex in hassan's answer.

Comment: not working:$content = var_dump("test.php");    
 $removedPhptags = preg_replace('/^<\?php(.*?)\?>)?$/s', '$1', $content);
 echo $removedPhptags;

Comment: how we can get including file also?